# FilteredSourceControl and CheckIns while Building

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

in our build process we commit created files back to the SVN Repository. To avoid an endless build/commit cycle I use the FilteredSourceControl-Block to ignore commit made by the user "CruiseControl".

It works as expected, as long nothing is committed before the build is finished.

This is what is happening:

1. 1st Commit
2. CC sees the change and begins the build process
3. 2nd Commit, Build process is still running
4. Build finishes and does a commit

Now the latest and greatest revision is the one made by CC, which is ignored as I told CC.

But my problem is, that the 2nd commit does not trigger an other build.

Has anyone an idea to work around this problem?

Comment: This looks like a bug, please report it to Jira.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit was that the time on the SVN server and the CruiseControl Server were not in sync. Check this if you have the same problem.